# Django media storage with Amazon 403 errors

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Although I have file uploads working fine in development, I can't get them to work in production with AWS S3.  I'm currently getting 403 errors:

```
S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden
```

I can see in my AWS IAM user access key ID that I get a last access recorded when the django app tried to connect.

However when I test the credentials with:

```
>>> import boto
>>> s3 = boto.connect_s3('access_key', 'secret_key')
>>> bucket = s3.get_bucket('mybucket')
```

then I also get a 403 forbidden access error, but for some reason the last access record doesn't appear in the AWS IAM dahboard, which makes me think that test isn't working for some reason?

---

common.py settings:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = str(APPS_DIR('media'))
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

production settings:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = env('DJANGO_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = env('DJANGO_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = env('DJANGO_AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
AWS_AUTO_CREATE_BUCKET = True

from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage
MediaRootS3BotoStorage = lambda: S3BotoStorage(location='media')
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'config.settings.production.MediaRootS3BotoStorage'

MEDIA_URL = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/%s/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
```

AWS environment vairables are setup in heroku.

upload done via:

```
class Bill(models.Model):
    service = models.ForeignKey(UserService
    bill = models.FileField(upload_to='bills', validators=[validate_file_extension])
```

Comment: Sounds like a permissions issue. Check your IAM permissions and the S3 bucket policy.

Comment: Note sure how to check IAM permissions apart from Users-> Security Credentials - The access key and secret key inthere are the ones I have used to test with.  The bucket permissions look ok List, Uplod/Delete, View permissions and edit permissions have been granted to the user (me) which is the access key and secret key I have used.

Answer (score 1):

`date ; sudo service ntp stop ; sudo ntpdate -s time.nist.gov ; sudo service ntp start ; date`

run this command once, if signature is invalid then AWS throws a 403.
I had the same issue earlier.